# Add a few table cells with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular.js and ng-repeat directive for creating a table cells. I have array with object:

```
$scope.items = [{ name: 'item1', value: [{ val1: '1' }, { val2: '2' }] }, 
                { name: 'item2', value: [{ val1: '3' }, { val2: '4' }] ]
```

and here is my markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" >
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="another_item in item.value">{{another_item.val1 + another_item.val2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Can somebody explain me, why is the second construction with td generate two tags. How does this construction work with plus in this case: {{another_item.val1 + another_item.val2}}

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ngRepeat iterates through the array and add the element it is in to the dom for every value.

In your case, iterating through items will add the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item1" >
   <td>{{item1.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="another_item in item2.value">{{another_item.val1 + another_item.val2}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="item2" >
   <td>{{item2.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="another_item in item2.value">{{another_item.val1 + another_item.val2}}</td>
</tr>
```

The inner ng-repeat does the same, so it becomes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item1" >
   <td>{{item1.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="firstIndex">{{firstIndex.val1 + firstIndex.val2}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="secondIndex">{{secondIndex.val1 + secondIndex.val2}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="item2" >
   <td>{{item2.name}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="firstIndex">{{firstIndex.val1 + firstIndex.val2}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="secondIndex">{{secondIndex.val1 + secondIndex.val2}}</td>
</tr>
```

See why it does not work? Since firstIndex only has val1, fails to add with val2. Opposite for secondIndex.